# Excel Formula to validate valid IP and valid URL in librecalc excel sheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula, libreoffice-calc, libreoffice-basic

Excel formulas to validate valid IP and valid URL in librecalc excel sheet.

For Valid IP got one formula as below,

`=AND((LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,".","")))=3,ISNUMBER(SUBSTITUTE(A1,".","")+0))`

But this command just checks if three dots are there or not. But it will not check the numbers before the first dot or the numbers after last dot.

Now wrt valid url please help to provide macro to say valid url.

I found the formula below but it is not working as expected,

`=IF(OR(LEFT(B90, 7) = "http://", LEFT(B90, 8) = "https://"), "Valid URL", "Not a valid URL")`

Please help to resolve this issue, Thank You.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I tried both of the spreadsheet formulas in Calc and they work. `12.34A5.2.101` is counted as invalid and so is `ttp://www.foo.org`. Please give complete examples of what should be considered invalid. Also, these are not macros, nor are they Basic language, and it sounds like you are asking about LO Calc, not MS Excel.

Comment: For IP address conceder below example,

Comment: @JimK
Below is example
12.34A5.2.101 - is invalid 
.345.2.101 or 12.345.2.  - it should throw invalid but it is considering as valid

Comment: @JimK about url i am not able to post 

changing https to http or viceversa should be valid but it is throwing as invalid

Comment: What version of Excel? Are these IP addresses within a sentence or do they stand alone in the cell?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld librecalc version is - Version: 6.4.7.2.

Yes, cell has only ip address not in sentence, but it is text field not number field..

Comment: @So not an excel solution from what you post? You should change your tags.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [REGEX spreadsheet function](https://help.libreoffice.org/latest/en-US/text/scalc/01/func_regex.html). Here is a Calc formula to check IP addresses.

```
=IF(ISNA(REGEX(A1;"^([:digit:]{1,3}\.){3}[:digit:]{1,3}"));"invalid";"valid")
```

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| .345.2.101 | invalid |
| 12.345.2.101 | valid |
| 12.34A5.2.101 | invalid |
| 12.345.2 | invalid |

You can write a similar formula for URLs.

Comment: `12.345.2.101` is not a valid IP4 address

Comment: `^(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])$` should work in Libre Office, but I don't have it installed so cannot test it.